# What is blocking my Java mail?

Tags: java, servlets, windows-7, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a web application developed with "pure" JSP, Servlet and Hibernate. It is also working with Java Mail. The Java mail function is working almost every machine we tested here, until today. It didn't work on the deployment server (it is actually a windows 7 PC I think bcs it has a GUI). It gave me the below error

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.xxx.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:69
7)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at RemindeWorker.Listener.MailClient.sendEmail(MailClient.java:65)
        at Filter.AuthenticationFilter_Level1.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter_Leve
l1.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI
mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
va:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:312)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
        ... 25 more
Level1 executed
NUM is: 1
```

Below is my Code.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package RemindeWorker.Listener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class MailClient 
{

    public void sendEmail(final String userName, final String password, final String host, final String html, final List<String>emails, String subject) throws MessagingException
    {
        System.out.println("User Name: "+userName);
        System.out.println("Password: "+password);
        System.out.println("Host: "+host);

//          String host="mail.xxx.com";  
//          final String user="abc@xxx.com";//change accordingly  
//          final String password="knight55";//change accordingly  



           //Get the session object  
           Properties props = new Properties();  
           props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,password);  
              }  
            });  

           if(!emails.isEmpty())
           {
                   //Compose the message  
                    InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[emails.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++) {
                        address[i] = new InternetAddress(emails.get(i));
                    }

                     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
                     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));  
                      message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                     message.setSubject(subject);  

                     message.setContent(html,"text/html");

                    //send the message  
                     Transport.send(message);  

                     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("No Recieptions");
           }


    }
}
```

What kind of thing is stopping my application from sending emails? The sever is having JRE 8 and XAMPP. Server admin says the firewall is turned off!

Comment: I'm not sure about your case mate, But I know for fact AWS(amazon) blocks many of  smtp connections(eventhough the firewall is down). so just make sure where you program is set up, it doesn't have such restrictions.(aws requires special unblocking of smtp request)

Comment: have you turned on the firewall on the machine which is being accessed for email?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: The email machine, actually it is a web domain with an email address. You know when you purchase a domain you also get a email creating facility.

Comment: @nafas: No, this is not AWS.

Comment: @JustCause what I meant was that where ever it is make sure they don't put special block on smtp

Comment: @nafas:The server admin at their side told there are no blocks. How to check whether there is any block?

Comment: JavaMail connection debugging tips are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that port 25 was blocked in the server by somehow. The default port for SMTP is port 25. I changed the port for the Java mail using `Properties` and it worked.